# reduce() method in JavaScript does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, javascript-objects

I having to issues  with my code.
the first one is that I am trying to format The **Total** as currency but it does not work.
my second issues is I am using the Reduce() method to track and calculate the price when ever the user selects the item till here it works find, but when the user unselects an item it goes  back to zero . I do not that I just want to mince it and keep the selected once .

```
const items = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducers.selectedItems.items);
 
const Total = items
  .map((item) => Number(item.price.replace("$", "")))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
    
const USD = Total.toLocaleString("en", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD",
});
```

Comment: Clarify the first issue, what exactly doesn't work. What you expect and what you get? Regarding the second issue, use a ref to store previous selected items and read from it so even if the state changes the value will remain there.

Comment: toLocaleString expects a number as input - ie. let num = 1000;
num.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"USD"}) this will give you an output of '$1,000.00' - this also means that your replace function is unnecessary, as the toLocaleString will add the '$'

Comment: For the second issue, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve - mapping and reducing will not change the original array, so items will go back to its original value on each render

Comment: okay the price var in the array is like this 12.50$ so it string . fisrt I have to replace the $ with empty string so it become like this "12.50" the format it as a number so I can calculate. till here it works fine. but when I unselect an item it becomes 0 again

Comment: First issue I expect the output to be like this $12.50 but it prints 12.50

Comment: yes it needs to be 'en-US', and it should be a number being passed in

Comment: reduce works exactly the way it's supposed to: please change your title to summarize the _actual_ problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `en` to `en-US`

```
 const USD = Total.toLocaleString('en-US',
  {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}
);
```